Latex Rendering in Pyplot different from Jupyter Markdown
I have an equation:
eq = r"$p\left(m^i = safe\right) = \prod_{l = 1}^N p\left(^{l}m^i = safe\right) \ \forall i \in [1,n]$"
Which (in Markdown, VS Code) renders to:

But when I input it in Matplotlib, it becomes:

Which is not what I want, because I prefer the writing style and the font used in the one showed in Markdown. Here's the code to reproduce the Matplotlib one:
def latex_to_jpg(equation, file_name):

    plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
    plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r"\usepackage{amsmath}"

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (1,1))
    ax.text(0.5,0.5, equation, size = 30, ha = 'center', va = 'center',
            color = 'k', weight = 'bold')
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.show()

Why are they different? And how can I output the style as seen in Markdown in Matplotlib?
Also, additionally, why am I not able to output a latex code in Matplotlib if it contains a \text{} command in the equation? Whenever I do, it gives me a massively long error code. How do I fix this?
